# Is the undiscounted value process of a Euro call option under Bachelier model a Martingale?

Tags: options, finance-mathematics, no-arbitrage-theory, fundamentals

Assume that $c_t$ is the UNDISCOUNTED price process for a European call option in Bachelier model. In [Bachelier model call option pricing formula](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/32863/bachelier-model-call-option-pricing-formula) the formulas is discussed. The  undiscounted value process is $c_t = (S_t-K)\Phi( \frac{S_t-K}{\sigma\sqrt{T-t}})+\sigma\sqrt{T-t}\phi( \frac{S_t-K}{\sigma\sqrt{T-t}})$.

**Is $c_t$ a martingale process?**

My personal guess is YES, because of the first fundamental theorem of asset pricing.  Am I correct?

Comment: No it isn't. Only **discounted** asset prices can be martingales. A discounted European call is a martingale under **any** model. To prove it, note that the price of an European call is a conditional expectation, then use the [Law of Iterated Expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).

Comment: Please look at page 4, first line of text. According to  this article it is martingale??
http://janroman.dhis.org/finance/SABR/ZABR%20Andreasen.pdf

Comment: In the article you link rates are assumed to be null, so in that case yes because the undiscounted call price is equal to the discounted call price.

Answer (score 2):

Let $c_t$ be the price of an European call with maturity $T$ and $D_{t,T}$ the discount factor from $T$ to $t$. We assume deterministic rates. Then note that for $s<t\leq T$:
$$\begin{align}
E^Q_s\left(c_t\right)&=E^Q_s\left(E^Q_t\left(D_{t,T}(S_T-K)^+\right)\right)
\\[3pt]
&=E^Q_s\left(D_{t,T}(S_T-K)^+\right)
\\[3pt]
&=E^Q_s\left(\frac{D_{s,t}}{D_{s,t}}D_{t,T}(S_T-K)^+\right)
\\
&=\frac{c_s}{D_{s,t}}\end{align}$$
because $D_{s,t}D_{t,T}=D_{s,T}$. The second inequality stems from the fact that:
$$E^Q_s(E^Q_t(\cdot))=E^Q_s(\cdot)$$ 
if $s<t$, this is the Law of Iterated Expectations. From the last equation you see $c_t$ is not a martingale, however rearranging:
$$E^Q_s\left(D_{s,t}c_t\right)=D_{s,s}c_s=c_s$$
Thus the discounted call price is a martingale. As you can see this is a model-free result.