# Bachelier model call option pricing formula with leverage and spread

Tags: option-pricing, bachelier

the call option pricing formula for the plain/vanilla payoff ($S_T-K)^+$) has been resolved, under the Bachelier model here:
[Bachelier model call option pricing formula](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/32863/bachelier-model-call-option-pricing-formula)

But can anyone help me with with the generalized payoff (with a leverage and a spread): $(L*(S_T+a)-K)^+$ ?

For this pay-off, what would be the call option pricing formula?

Thanks in advance for the help, and sorry if this is an obvious question (i'm new in the field).

Comment: Habe you already tried anything so far? If so, please let is know where you’re stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align}
  \left( L\times(S_T+\alpha)-K \right)^ + {} & = max \{  L\times(S_T+\alpha)-K,0\} \\
   {}&= max \left \{   L \times\left( S_T+\alpha-\frac{K}{L}\right),0\right \} \\
   {}&\stackrel{\dagger}{=}L \times  max \left \{      S_T+\alpha-\frac{K}{L} ,0\right \} \\
{}& =L \times  max \left \{      S_T- \left( \frac{K}{L} -\alpha\right),0\right \} \\
\end{align}
By setting $K':= \frac{K}{L} -\alpha$ you can value the option as a vanilla call  with strike $K'$ and scale the resulting price by $L$, accordingly. Note that in $(\dagger)$, we have used the [property:](https://gist.github.com/paniq/3f882c50f1790e323482)

$$max(x \times a,y \times  a) = a \; max(x,y) \ \ if  \ \ (a \geq 0) $$

Comment: thanks a lot Alex !